# Tic Tac Toe Application using android:button

Tags: android

I am trying to build a tic tac toe application using the android:button. Right now I am thinking of the best way to design this because I am not sure how to detect buttons that are adjacent to each other. Right now i have things hard coded, how do i detect if buttons are adjacent to one another?

Comment: Please post your code or give more details about the specific trouble you are having...

Comment: Basically you must give each button an id. If your tic-tac-toe is 3 rows with 3 columns you could give each button an id that reveals what row and column number it is on. 

123
456
789

Comment: you could put your Button objects into a Button[3][3]. That would give you easy programmatic access to them based on position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use id with row/column major  pattern / 2D array of Buttons which makes is easy to determine adjacent buttons  like(3x3) :

```
00 01 02
10 11 12
20 21 22
```

or

```
00 10 20
01 11 21
02 12 22
```

---

Here is a complete sample for you:[Tic-Tac-Toe](http://hackingheart.wordpress.com/2012/03/08/how-to-built-android-apps-tic-tac-toe/), also take a look at [Tic-Tac-Toe-2](http://www.androidadb.com/source/tictactoe4android-read-only/src/com/android/project/TicTacToe.java.html)